# what's the purpose of chef repository?

Tags: chef-infra

I am a newbie for Chef. After installing, the document prompt me to clone a chef repository from git. I am wondering what's the purpose of chef repository. If I only need to use it as a chef client.

Comment: You don't need it if you have your own cookbooks. Chef repository is where cookbooks, data bags and all other info concerning chef is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chef repository gives structure to organizing all the artifacts (cookbooks, recipes, roles, etc.) that are used with chef to describe and ultimately configure your infrastructure. The repository is needed at development time when you create your own cookbooks, modify existing ones and upload them to your chef server. Think of the repository as a workspace for implementing your infrastructure as code.

The chef documentation refers to a development machine as a **chef workstation**. A workstation has one or more repositories for managing the infrastructure artifacts and the knife tool to interact with a chef server.

The repository and knife are not needed on a regular node that is *managed* by chef. That's where the chef client is all that's needed. Conversely, a workstation is used to *manage* chef. The repository and knife are tools for that.

Some things like roles and databags that you can work on in a repository you could also define with the chef server web UI, but then you'd not have a version controlled history of your work. For cookbooks, even if you don't need to modify any, you still need to upload them to the server from a repository using knife.

See the chef wiki for more information: [workstation](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Workstation+Setup), [repository](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Repository), [knife](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Knife).

Comment: this is a good explanation.  i'm a big fan of chef and find it far more intuitive with better documentation then say puppet, but this was an area of confusion for me.  in the end, i think it's safe to say that "chef-repo" really isn't a *thing* at all.  It's a suggested "pattern" that they assigned a cute name.  it's still up to you to sync the contents with version control and use knife to upload all the entities that matter to you into chef-server.  the cute name leaves the read thinking there's more to this than there is IMO